# OpenID Connect - use OpenID Provider to authenticate an existing accounts system

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I've tried to research but am not finding anything useful, but maybe I don't know what to search.

**Task**

I have to set up an OpenID Connect callback URL to supply to a custom OpenID Provider.

**Background**

Prior to any logins of any kind we populate our database with accounts from the 3rd party.
Then send emails out to collect data for each account later via user form interactions in our system.

The 3rd party website has accounts I assume provided by their OP. Our system has accounts which are generated by fetching their accounts via API and generating them locally in our system (this process can't change).

They want to send a user from their website to ours with SSO, via OpenID Connect.

**What to do**

Now I understand how to setup an endpoint that receives a token and that it needs to be sent back with 'direct back channel' to get an understandable ID token (from reading OpenID docs).

I assume the easiest thing would be to compare the token to something we collected via API that defines each unique user account (for example their accounts UUID). I don't know what is available from a ID token..
Once I have ascertained which account is trying to authenticate/login I can programatically authenticate via our system and redirect to the appropriate page.

Is this plausible? - seems hacky as this seems to ignore everything OpenID Connect is providing?

Answer (score 0):

> They want to send a user from their website to ours with SSO, via OpenID Connect.

As I can understand from your explanation, what you require is to enable access to your system for users that are hosted (stored) in a third party authorization server.

This is similar to what you see in "Login with Facebook" or "Login with Google" scenario. Basically you are extracting user data from a trusted identity provider (AKA authorization server) and create a user in your system. If your third party holds an identity provider which get exposed to your system and allows your system to use something similar to "Login with System X", then you may go ahead to implement that. And when you receive ID token from the login, you may compare its value to previously fetched user data. For this you may use something like a user ID , email or simply an ID understood by both systems.

Regarding SSO, if the systems runs on a browser and user has already logged in, user may not require to re-login when "Login with System X" is clicked. Which is similar to using Google login.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I havent worded my question very well.  This is my main issue - I DONT want to create a user from the 'Login with facebook' style system.  I already have the user setup.  Every account that will exist already exists prior to ever being redirected to our site. 

There will be no way on our system to choose how to login either, you login via our systems account.  

I need a way of Website A redirecting user to Website B and there being a user in  Website B that somehow matches up with the one on Website A